# Symmetric HEADER and FOOTER in LaTeX

Tags: positioning

I just want to  write some LaTeX code to get a Beamer style test. The problem is that, the default template is designed for one page printing.

However, in my case, I want to get a Symmetric Header and Footer as the one in the 'twoside' document. That's, I want to put the margin note on left side of odd page, on right side of even page. Is that possbile in LaTeX?

Well, this is how it looks

[image]

However, these two page should be symmetric on my initial purpose.

The main code for generating the margin note goes as follows

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document components (in TikZ) %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%__________________
\newcommand\Header{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[qfcolor]
(current page.north west) -- (current page.north east) --
([yshift=50pt]current page.north east|-current page text area.north east) --
([yshift=50pt,xshift=-3cm]current page.north|-current page text area.north) --
([yshift=10pt,xshift=-5cm]current page.north|-current page text area.north) --
([yshift=10pt]current page.north west|-current page text area.north west) -- cycle;
%
% Logo UL HPC
%\node (logo_hpc)[xshift=0.8cm,yshift=-0.2cm,rounded corners,anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo_ULHPC.pdf}};     %% logo：
\node (logo_hpc)[xshift=0.3cm,yshift=-0.2cm,rounded corners,anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) 
%%{\includegraphics[width=4.8cm, height=6.4cm]{logos/logo_5.jpg}};     %% logo：logos/logo_4.jpg
{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm, height=6.0cm]{\Logo}};     %% logo：logos/logo_4.jpg
%% \node (logo_hpc)[xshift=0.8cm,yshift=-0.2cm,rounded corners,anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.jpg}};             %% logo：logo.jpg

%%    \node (header) [font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},anchor=east,xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-1.5cm] at (current page.north east) {
 \node (header) [font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},anchor=east,xshift=-9.5cm,yshift=-0.65cm] at (current page.north east) {
%%      \fontsize{25}{50}\selectfont \Newstitle
   \fontsize{12}{25}\selectfont \Newstitle
};

\node (header) [font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},anchor=east,xshift=-6.5cm,yshift=-1.7cm] at (current page.north east) {
  \fontsize{25}{50}\selectfont \shouxie \Newssubtitle
};

\node (date) [font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{qfcolor},anchor=east,yshift=1cm] at (current page text area.north east) {
  %% Issue \Number\ -- \ReleaseDate\  
  \small  \Number\ -- \ReleaseDate\  
  %-- \href{\NewsletterURL}{online version}

};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% 
\node (qrcode)[font=\color{qfcolor},anchor=south] at ($(current page text area.north east)+(1,0.3)$) { 
  %% \qrcode[version=3,height=1.2cm]{\NewsletterURL}
  \qrcode[version=3,height=1.2cm]{\NewsletterURL}
};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\node (page) [yshift=-0.4cm,font=\ttfamily\bfseries\color{white}, anchor=east] at (current page.north east) { };
%   \thepage~
% };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%_________________
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% ：\Left
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \newcommand\Left{%                                                              
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (up)   at   (current page text area.north west);
\coordinate (down) at   (current page text area.south west);
%%%% \coordinate (editors) at ($(current page.north west)+(2.5,-4.75)$);
\coordinate (editors) at ($(current page.north west)+(2.7,-4.15)$);


\draw [thick,color={qfcolor}] ($(up)+(-0.5,0)$) -- ($(down)+(-0.5,0)$);  

%fill=lightgray, rounded corners
%%%%    \node (docinfo)[font=\sffamily\color{qfcolor},anchor=north, text width=5.1cm] at (editors) {
\node (docinfo)[font=\sffamily\color{qfcolor},anchor=north, text width=4.2cm] at (editors) {
  \tiny
%%%      \begin{tabular}{rp{4cm}}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
 \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{rp{3.4cm}}
    %\hline\\
    \textbf{\scriptsize Date:}      & \scriptsize \PublishDate \\ %\ReleaseDate  \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
     \end{tabular}
    %      \textcolor{qfcolor}{\textbf{Editors:} \Editors}

};
\end{tikzpicture}%

}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% New command to facilitate the placement of content in the left panel
% Format: \leftinfo{<title>}{<body>}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\leftinfo}[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%%%% \coordinate (editors) at ($(current page.north west)+(2.5,-4.75)$); % See above
\coordinate (editors) at ($(current page.north west)+(2.5,-5.15)$); % See above
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% \node (left_title)[font=\sffamily\color{ulblue},fill=lightgray,rounded rectangle west arc=none,anchor=north, inner sep=1em,text width=4.4cm] at ($(editors)+(0.2,-2)$) {
\node (left_title)[font=\sffamily\color{ulblue},fill=lightgray,rounded rectangle west arc=none,anchor=north, inner sep=.5em,text width=4.6cm] at ($(editors)+(0.2,-2)$) {
  \hspace{1em} \large \textbf{#1}
  %\fontsize{15}{50}\selectfont \textbf{#1}
};
 %%%%  \node [font=\sffamily\color{ulblue},anchor=west, text width=5cm,below=0.3cm of left_title]  {
 \node [font=\sffamily\color{ulblue},anchor=west, text width=4.2cm,below=0.3cm of left_title]  {
   \small \textbf{#2}
 };
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \vspace{-2em}
}
 \newcommand\ulhpctoc{


%% \leftinfo{In this issue...}{\vspace*{-0.25cm}\tableofcontents}                           

%% 

 \leftinfo{...}{\vspace*{-0.45cm}\tableofcontents} 
   }

  %__________________
 \newcommand\Footer{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[qfcolor]
(current page.south west) -- (current page.south east) --
([yshift=-40pt]current page.south east|-current page text area.south east) --
([yshift=-40pt,xshift=-3cm]current page.south|-current page text area.south) --
([xshift=-5cm,yshift=-10pt]current page.south|-current page text area.south) --
([yshift=-10pt]current page.south west|-current page text area.south west) -- cycle;

\node (licence_logo) [yshift=0.25cm, anchor=west] at (current page.south west) {
  %% \href{\LicenceURL}{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{logo_licence.png}}                             %% logo_licence.png
};

\node (licence) [yshift=0.45cm,font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}, anchor=west, right=-0.1 of licence_logo] { 
%%      \tiny \href{\DocSrcURL}{\color{white}\underline{\LaTeX\ sources}}.
  %%      Template by \href{mailto=Sebastien.Varrette@uni.lu}{\color{white}\underline{S. Varrette}}.                      %% 

};

\node (licence) [yshift=0.15cm,font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}, anchor=west, right=-0.1 of licence_logo] { 
%%      \tiny \href{\DocSrcURL}{\color{white}\underline{\LaTeX\ sources}}.
%%      Template by \href{mailto=Sebastien.Varrette@uni.lu}{\color{white}\underline{S. Varrette}}.                      %% 
};


\node (social) [xshift=2.2cm,anchor=west, above=0.8cm of licence_logo]  {
  \fontsize{22}{24}\selectfont 
  \href{http://twitter.com/\Twitter}{\color{white}\faTwitter}
  \href{http://github.com/\Github}{\color{white}\faGithubSign}
  \href{mailto:hpc-sysadmins@uni.lu}{\color{white}\faEnvelope}
  %\href{mailto:hpc-users@uni.lu}{\color{white}\faGroup}
  %\href{https://hpc.uni.lu/users/getting_started.html}{\color{white}\faQuestion}
};

\node (url) [yshift=1.15cm,xshift=-.5cm, font=\ttfamily\bfseries\color{white}, anchor=east] at (current page.south east) {
  \fontsize{12}{20}\selectfont \href{\InstituteURL}{\color{white}{\faSignin\ \InstituteURL}}~~~ 
};

 %\node (page) [yshift=0.25cm,font=\ttfamily\bfseries\color{ulblue}, anchor=east] at (current page.south east) {
 %  \thepage~~
 %};


  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

% Reset space for itemize
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{itemsep=0pt}

%\pagestyle{empty}
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{\Header\Left\Footer}}
%\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{\Header\Left\Footer}}
```

Comment: It seems odd to have an alternating layout for a beamer document, as it was intended for presentations, where I would find such a detail very distracting. If you are only preparing this for printing, I would advise you to look into a different documentclass.

Comment: The document is not for screen-presentation, but for bullet-printing. Hence, it would be better if some could help me out.